# An error when I try to run my android studio program

Tags: java, android-studio, android-manifest, execution-time

When I try to run the program it appears:
"Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @7c389728"
[It also appears:Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JrRv.png)

I want to try to solve this and see how my program is going

Comment: Avoid down votes, by not posting images, here is why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1847378

Answer (score 1):

I'm also getting this issue and solved by appending

```
 --add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
```

in `org.gradle.jvmargs= ...`  property

to the file  `./android/gradle.properties`

hope it will help you